# cannot execute anything after a loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def getStockOut(stockName):
    stocksdata = get_stock_data(stockName)
    stocksout = []
    for i in range(len(stocksdata)):
        stock = mine.trend(stocksdata['Close'][stockName[i]],200)
        stock.main()
        uptrendo = 0
        downtrendo = 0
        leno = len(stock.getTrend())
        if stock.getTrend()[leno-1] > 0:
           uptrendo = stock.getTrend()[leno-1]
        if stock.getTrend()[leno-1] < 0:
           downtrendo = stock.getTrend()[leno-1]
        macd = mine.macd(stocksdata['Close'][stockName[i]])
        ema = stock.getNearToEma()[len(stock.getNearToEma())-1]
        class outs:
            upTrend = Decimal(uptrendo)
            downTrend = Decimal(downtrendo)
            distanceToEma = Decimal(ema)
            macdLine = Decimal(macd[0][len(macd[0])-1])
            signalLine = Decimal(macd[1][len(macd[1])-1])
            histogram = Decimal(macd[2][len(macd[2])-1])
            name = stockName[i]
        stocksout.append(outs)
        print("helloo")
    print("huh")
    return stocksout
```

in the above code what i expecting is to run sone code after the loop
but its not executing and not returning anything
here i passed 69 names to the function so,
"helloo" is printed 69 times
but "huh" is not printing
i just used these print to describe it
the result i want to see is to return stocksout value